# Promise.then or Promise.catch when a Promise throws error

Tags: javascript, promise

When a promise throws an error and we have to catch it just so it won't show "Uncaught dummy error", I found those similar approaches:

Using Promise.then:
`const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {throw 'dummy error'}).then(null, error => console.error(error));`

Using Promise.catch:
`const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {throw 'dummy error'}).catch(error => console.error(error));`

What should be the best practice to follow in this scenario?

When tested, both approaches are returning 'dummy error' in console.

Comment: `.catch()` [calls `.then()` under the hood](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#description). It is just syntactic sugar over `.then(null /* undefined */, () => {})`.

Comment: This is not opinion-based, there's clear and obvious differences.

Comment: @Evert There are no differences?

Comment: @Bergi only if you remove all context. The answer from rveerd is a great example, plus legibility.

Comment: @Evert The question is asking about the difference between `then(null, …)` and `.catch(…)` (which is none), not about [the difference between `.then(…, …)` and `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi 100% agree they are functionally identical. I guess I'm arguing one of those is better in terms of how people will interpret it and potentially introduce bugs. I believe that difference is not opinion-based.

Comment: @Evert Ah, yes, totally agree. I had voted to reopen as well

Answer (score -1):

They are not the same when the result callback (the first argument to `then()`) throws an error itself.

```js
Promise.resolve('done')
  .then(
    () => { throw new Error('doh!')},
    (err) =>  console.error('I cannot catch the error thrown in .then', err)
  );

Promise.resolve('done')
  .then(() => { throw new Error('doh!')})
  .catch((err) => console.error('I can catch the error thrown in .then', err));
```

Because of this I prefer the second form. But you should use `async`/`await` if possible.

Comment: That is not what OP is doing. (If they were, it would be a duplicate of the canonical [When is `.then(success, fail)` considered an antipattern for promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572))